# Why doesn't my button click work?

Tags: c#, winforms, click

I'm trying to write a Fahrenheit to Celsius converter but nothing happens when I click the button 
and I have no idea why. Please help me.

It's written in C# and I have a form with a label, a button, a textbox for input, and a multiline textbox for output.

```
namespace _14._6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            int farenhait;
            int celsius;

            farenhait = Convert.ToInt32(textbox2.Text);
            celsius = Convert.ToInt32(5.0 / 9.0 * (farenhait - 32));
            textBox1.Text = farenhait + "grader på farenhait skalan motsvarar \n " + celsius + "grader celsius";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see in the debugger?

Comment: Probably you deleted the button and re-added it so the event was cleared. You need to add it again from  the designer.

Comment: I can't see the problem right away, does the method get called (breakpoint)?

Comment: In the IDE (debugger) make sure you have valid data for `farenhait` and `celsius`. And make sure `textBox1` is where you want to display the result.

Answer (score 7):

**Assuming the statement:**

> but nothing happends when i klick the button...

is literally true (*i.e. when placing a breakpoint on the first line in the handler `button1_Click` it doesn't hit the breakpoint*) then something happened to the handler. So, go to the Form Designer and double-click the button again to hookup the handler.

Answer (score 2):

Is the event wired up?

Click on the button in the designer and look in the properties window (bottom-right underneath your file list), then click the events button (looks like a little lightning bolt) and scroll down until you find `Click`, then type `button1_Click` in there if it isn't already in there, that will wire the event up.

Alternatively, you can add it manually in the form's constructor:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does the debugger tell you is wrong?

Not to deviate to far from your original question, I would suggest to use a technique called abstraction.  An example of this would be to create a separate class, which will take parameters that will accomplish a task.

```
public class TemperatureConverter
{
    public void Convertion(int fahrenheit, int celsius)
    {
          // Input your conversion syntax here.
    }
}
```

Now with that particular class can handle the conversion, on your form within your button you can provide the necessary *Error Handling* then you can actually call it with those values.

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Error Handling

     TemperatureConverter tc = new TemperatureConverter();
     tc.Conversion(textbox1.Text, textbox2.Text);
}
```

In this example which is quite poor, you'll have to cast the *string* to a *integer* otherwise it will error.  But this is an example to help better adhere to Object-Orientation.

Your other issue: "nothing happens when I click the button".  This leads me to believe the *EventHandler* has been broken.  Follow these steps:

1. Go into Designer Mode
2. Select your Button
3. Open Properties
4. You'll see a button with almost a lightning bolt, click it
5. Locate your on click, and ensure the EventHandler is wired correctly.

This is a designer approach to the coded approach that Sean provided.

Hopefully this helps.